# How do I use a switch statement from another panel?

Tags: java, swing

I'm working on a project for a class that's essentially a slot machine of sorts. It had 3 columns on the top that lets the user click a button to change the shape in the panel above it. On the bottom is the actual slot machine and the goal is to try and guess what the "slot machine" will show after it's been spun. I've written the panels and the switch statement though I'm having trouble changing the shapes in the panels that the user is supposed to change on the top. Could anyone put me in the right direction on how to go about this?

This is the panel that creates the buttons and their actions:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SlotPanel extends JPanel {
 ImagePanel slotOne, slotTwo, slotThree; // three panels for the computer to 
generate
 ImagePanel userOne, userTwo, userThree; // three panels chosen by the user

// Panels used in SlotPanel
 JPanel titlePanel, guessPanel, slotTitlePanel;
 JPanel selectOnePanel, selectTwoPanel, selectThreePanel;
 JLabel title, guess, slotTitle;
 JButton selectOne, selectTwo, selectThree, spinMachine;
 private int currentShape;

 public SlotPanel() {
 currentShape = 0;
 // Instantiate all the objects declared above
slotOne=new ImagePanel(); slotTwo=new ImagePanel(); slotThree=new ImagePanel();
userOne=new ImagePanel(); userTwo=new ImagePanel(); userThree=new ImagePanel();

titlePanel=new JPanel();
guessPanel=new JPanel();
slotTitlePanel=new JPanel();
title = new JLabel("Austin's Wheel of Wacky Shapes"); // Change this label for the top of the display section for the default display
guess = new JLabel("Your Guess");
slotTitle = new JLabel("Slot Machine Wheel");
selectOnePanel=new JPanel(); selectTwoPanel=new JPanel(); selectThreePanel=new JPanel();
// Each of the three buttons to select the object has the same label
selectOne=new JButton("Wheel 1"); selectTwo=new JButton("Wheel 2"); selectThree=new JButton("Wheel 3");
// Button to spin the machine at the bottom
spinMachine=new JButton("Spin Machine!");

ObjectChanger listener = new ObjectChanger();
selectOne.addActionListener (listener);
selectTwo.addActionListener (listener);
selectThree.addActionListener (listener);

setBackgroundColor(Color.gray);
setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350, 415));

// Select the sizes for each of the panels
titlePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,20));
guessPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,20));
slotTitlePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,20));
selectOnePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(110, 50));
selectOnePanel.setBackground(Color.red);
selectTwoPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(110, 50));
selectTwoPanel.setBackground(Color.red);
selectThreePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(110, 50));
selectThreePanel.setBackground(Color.red);
spinMachine.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(240, 20));
selectOne.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(110,30));
selectTwo.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(110,30));
selectThree.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(110,30));
// Action listeners that will take care of the changing of the objects displayed
selectOne.addActionListener(new ObjectChanger());
selectTwo.addActionListener(new ObjectChanger());
selectThree.addActionListener(new ObjectChanger());
// Action listener to get the "machine" in motion
spinMachine.addActionListener(new Spin());
slotOne.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(110,100));
slotOne.setBackground(Color.white);
slotTwo.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(110,100));
slotTwo.setBackground(Color.white);
slotThree.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(110,100));
slotThree.setBackground(Color.white);


// Add the title JLabel to the top panel
titlePanel.add(title);
guessPanel.add(guess);
slotTitlePanel.add(slotTitle);
// Add the selection button to the user-selectable panel one
selectOnePanel.add(selectOne); //
// Add the selection button to the user-selectable panel two
selectTwoPanel.add(selectTwo);
// Add the selection button to the user-selectable panel three
selectThreePanel.add(selectThree);

add(titlePanel);
add(guessPanel);
add(userOne);
add(userTwo);
add(userThree);
add(selectOnePanel);
add(selectTwoPanel);
add(selectThreePanel);
add(spinMachine);
add(slotTitlePanel);
add(slotOne);
add(slotTwo);
add(slotThree);
}

public void setBackgroundColor(Color color){

}

// ActionListener class to determine which shape button was pressed
public class ObjectChanger implements ActionListener{

 @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

    //Identifies which buttons have been pressed to change their according slot wheel
      if (event.getSource() == selectOne);{
        while (currentShape == 0){
          switch (currentShape){
              case 0:
                  currentShape++;
              break;
              case 1:
                  currentShape++;
              break;
              case 2:
                  currentShape++;
              break;
              case 3:
                  currentShape = 0;
              break;
          }
        }
      }
    if (event.getSource() == selectTwo);{
        while (currentShape == 0){
          switch (currentShape){
              case 0:
                  currentShape++;
              break;
              case 1:
                  currentShape++;
              break;
              case 2:
                  currentShape++;
              break;
              case 3:
                  currentShape = 0;
              break;
          }
          }
      }
    if (event.getSource() == selectThree);{
        while (currentShape == 0){
          switch (currentShape){
              case 0:
                  currentShape++;
              break;
              case 1:
                  currentShape++;
              break;
              case 2:
                  currentShape++;
              break;
              case 3:
                  currentShape = 0;
              break;
          }
          }
      }
    }
}

// ActionListener class to determine when the Spin button is called

public class Spin implements ActionListener{

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
    Random generator = new Random();

        //Changes the background color to green if all of the wheels match
        //or red if even one does not match to its designated wheel
        if (slotOne == userOne && slotTwo == userTwo && slotThree == userThree)
            setBackgroundColor(Color.green);
        else
            setBackgroundColor(Color.red);


    }
  }
}
```

And this is the Image Panel I've made that creates the panels that are being changed:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

// This class describes each of the Image Panels (6 total displayed)
// And provides methods for drawing of the shapes
public class ImagePanel extends JPanel{
// Use an int value to keep the current shape for the object
private int currentShape, count;
// Constructs the panels by assigning their shape and size
public ImagePanel() {
setPreferredSize(new Dimension(110,100));
setBackground(Color.black);
currentShape = 0;

}

// Redraws the object after "Spin" has been selected
public void changeShape(){
  currentShape++;
  if (currentShape > 3)
        currentShape = 0;

  // Repaint is called
  repaint();
}

// Used when the "SpinMachine" button is called to randomly generate shapes
public void changeShape(int setShape){
  currentShape=setShape;
  repaint();
}

// Accessor for the shape
public int getShape(){
  return currentShape;
}

// PaintComponent method takes care of the drawing
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

  super.paintComponent(g);
  g.setColor(Color.blue);

//Switch method to change between the four shapes needed for the slot machine
  switch (currentShape) {
    case 0: g.fillRect(25, 20, 35, 70);  
    break;
    case 1: 
      g.fillOval(25, 20, 70, 70);
      break;
    case 2:
      int x[]={55,15,95}, y[]={25,95,95};
      g.fillPolygon(x,y,3);
      break;
    case 3:
       g.fillRect(25, 25, 70, 35);
      break;
    default:
      break;
   }
  }
 }
```

Thank you for any help I get in advance!

Comment: What you need is some kind of model and observer pattern. The model holds and controls the state, when the state changes it generates notifications to all the interested parties.  Have a look at [model-view-controller](https://blog.codinghorror.com/understanding-model-view-controller/) and [observer pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html) for more details

Answer (score -1):

Ok so here is the working version of your code, with a walk through of what was going wrong below, i added my own main method for testing purposes.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SlotPanel extends JPanel {

public static void main(String[] args){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("TESt");
    frame.add(new SlotPanel());
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
ImagePanel slotOne, slotTwo, slotThree; // three panels for the computer to 
//generate
ImagePanel userOne, userTwo, userThree; // three panels chosen by the user

// Panels used in SlotPanel
JPanel titlePanel, guessPanel, slotTitlePanel;
JPanel selectOnePanel, selectTwoPanel, selectThreePanel;
JLabel title, guess, slotTitle;
JButton selectOne, selectTwo, selectThree, spinMachine;
private int currentShape;

public SlotPanel() {
    currentShape = 0;
    // Instantiate all the objects declared above
    slotOne=new ImagePanel(); slotTwo=new ImagePanel(); slotThree=new ImagePanel();
    userOne=new ImagePanel(); userTwo=new ImagePanel(); userThree=new ImagePanel();

    titlePanel=new JPanel();
    guessPanel=new JPanel();
    slotTitlePanel=new JPanel();
    title = new JLabel("Austin's Wheel of Wacky Shapes"); // Change this label for the top of the display section for the default display
    guess = new JLabel("Your Guess");
    slotTitle = new JLabel("Slot Machine Wheel");
    selectOnePanel=new JPanel(); selectTwoPanel=new JPanel(); selectThreePanel=new JPanel();
    // Each of the three buttons to select the object has the same label
    selectOne=new JButton("Wheel 1"); selectTwo=new JButton("Wheel 2"); selectThree=new JButton("Wheel 3");
    // Button to spin the machine at the bottom
    spinMachine=new JButton("Spin Machine!");

    //Um why?
    //ObjectChanger listener = new ObjectChanger();
    //selectOne.addActionListener (listener);
    //selectTwo.addActionListener (listener);
    //selectThree.addActionListener (listener);

    setBackgroundColor(Color.gray);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350, 415));

    // Select the sizes for each of the panels
    titlePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,20));
    guessPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,20));
    slotTitlePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,20));
    selectOnePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(110, 50));
    selectOnePanel.setBackground(Color.red);
    selectTwoPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(110, 50));
    selectTwoPanel.setBackground(Color.red);
    selectThreePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(110, 50));
    selectThreePanel.setBackground(Color.red);
    spinMachine.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(240, 20));
    selectOne.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(110,30));
    selectTwo.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(110,30));
    selectThree.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(110,30));
    // Action listeners that will take care of the changing of the objects displayed
    selectOne.addActionListener(new ObjectChanger());
    selectTwo.addActionListener(new ObjectChanger());
    selectThree.addActionListener(new ObjectChanger());
    // Action listener to get the "machine" in motion
    spinMachine.addActionListener(new Spin());
    slotOne.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(110,100));
    slotOne.setBackground(Color.white);
    slotTwo.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(110,100));
    slotTwo.setBackground(Color.white);
    slotThree.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(110,100));
    slotThree.setBackground(Color.white);


    // Add the title JLabel to the top panel
    titlePanel.add(title);
    guessPanel.add(guess);
    slotTitlePanel.add(slotTitle);
    // Add the selection button to the user-selectable panel one
    selectOnePanel.add(selectOne); //
    // Add the selection button to the user-selectable panel two
    selectTwoPanel.add(selectTwo);
    // Add the selection button to the user-selectable panel three
    selectThreePanel.add(selectThree);

    add(titlePanel);
    add(guessPanel);
    add(userOne);
    add(userTwo);
    add(userThree);
    add(selectOnePanel);
    add(selectTwoPanel);
    add(selectThreePanel);
    add(spinMachine);
    add(slotTitlePanel);
    add(slotOne);
    add(slotTwo);
    add(slotThree);
}

public void setBackgroundColor(Color color){

}

// ActionListener class to determine which shape button was pressed
public class ObjectChanger implements ActionListener{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        //Identifies which buttons have been pressed to change their according slot wheel
        if (event.getSource() == selectOne){
            userOne.incrementCurrent();
        }
        if (event.getSource() == selectTwo){
            userTwo.incrementCurrent();
        }
        if (event.getSource() == selectThree){
            userThree.incrementCurrent();
        }
    }
}

// ActionListener class to determine when the Spin button is called

public class Spin implements ActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        Random generator = new Random();

        //Changes the background color to green if all of the wheels match
        //or red if even one does not match to its designated wheel
        if (slotOne == userOne && slotTwo == userTwo && slotThree == userThree)
            setBackgroundColor(Color.green);
        else
            setBackgroundColor(Color.red);


    }
}
}
```

Here is the second class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

// This class describes each of the Image Panels (6 total displayed)
// And provides methods for drawing of the shapes
public class ImagePanel extends JPanel{
// Use an int value to keep the current shape for the object
private int count;
private int currentShape;
// Constructs the panels by assigning their shape and size
public ImagePanel() {
setPreferredSize(new Dimension(110,100));
setBackground(Color.black);
currentShape = 0;

}
public void incrementCurrent(){
    currentShape++;
    if(currentShape>3)
        currentShape=0;
    changeShape(currentShape);
}
// Redraws the object after "Spin" has been selected
public void changeShape(){
  currentShape++;
  if (currentShape > 3)
        currentShape = 0;

  // Repaint is called
  repaint();
}

// Used when the "SpinMachine" button is called to randomly generate shapes
public void changeShape(int setShape){
  currentShape=setShape;
  repaint();
}

// Accessor for the shape
public int getShape(){
  return currentShape;
}

// PaintComponent method takes care of the drawing
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

  super.paintComponent(g);
  g.setColor(Color.blue);

//Switch method to change between the four shapes needed for the slot machine
  switch (currentShape) {
    case 0: g.fillRect(25, 20, 35, 70);  
    break;
    case 1: 
      g.fillOval(25, 20, 70, 70);
      break;
    case 2:
      int x[]={55,15,95}, y[]={25,95,95};
      g.fillPolygon(x,y,3);
      break;
    case 3:
       g.fillRect(25, 25, 70, 35);
      break;
    default:
      break;
   }
  }
 }
```

First: you added the actionListener twice both here:

```
ObjectChanger listener = new ObjectChanger();
selectOne.addActionListener (listener);
selectTwo.addActionListener (listener);
selectThree.addActionListener (listener);
```

and here:

```
selectOne.addActionListener(new ObjectChanger());
selectTwo.addActionListener(new ObjectChanger());
selectThree.addActionListener(new ObjectChanger());
```

Second you where using the currentShape value to try to change the shape in the JPanels, but the switch statement was a wierd way to do it since you only wanted to increment it, also once incremented you didnt actually do anything with the number becuase you never called the change shape method.  I added a incrementCurrent method in the ImagePanel class that now takes care of that.

```
   public void incrementCurrent(){
    currentShape++;
    if(currentShape>3)
        currentShape=0;
    changeShape(currentShape);
}
```

as this will now both change the value and repaint the shape.